# PHP video site parser

Tags: php, parsing, curl, simple-html-dom

so I've been working on a php parser. Essentially what is it supposed to do is parser filenuke for a video url. However, when running the following script and clicking play it says video not found, but when you load the regular filenuke URL the video plays. I don't know what to do, thanks!

```
<?php

include("simple_html_dom.php");

$url = "http://filenuke.com/fizzoquaog43";
$cookie = tmpfile();

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($contents);

$items = $html->find("input[name=id]");
$items2 = $html->find("input[name=fname]");
$items3 = $html->find("input[name=referrer]");
foreach($items as $element) {
    $fid = $element->value;
}
foreach($items2 as $element2) {
    $fname = $element2->value;
}
foreach($items3 as $element3) {
    $referrer = $element3->value;
}

$data = array(
        'op' => 'download1',
        'usr_login' => '',
        'method_free' => 'free',
        'referrer' => null,
        'id' => $fid,
        'filename' => $fname
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $page;

?>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me (didn't have the Simple DOM parser here but I recreated the same HTTP requests and the resulting page was playable locally).

On a sidenote: 'method_free' should be set to 'Free' when you intend to fully mimic the site. Also setting the referrer in the second request would be a good idea (but the site doesn't check for its correctness).

Comment: did you try playing the video? It won;t play if you test it out on a server

Comment: I tried it, first via the actual website, there the video started to stream after about 2 minutes.
On my local site nothing happened for 5 or 6 minutes but the HTTP request to the video.mp4 did not result in a 404 and it was still trying to load.

Comment: If i run it on a server, it goes through to the video player successfully, however when I click play the loading thing comes up and then it says "video not found" in the player.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using composer, you could try some php video url parser instead of making your own.

For example : https://github.com/ricardofiorani/php-video-url-parser